# Not able to change password of TP-Link wireless router TL-WR740N

Tags: wireless-networking, router, passwords, wifi-configuration

I am using TL-WR740N from TP-Link. I use Internet of [Spidigo](http://www.spidigo.com). Googling about it I find that I have to open tplinklogin.net or `http://192.168.1.1`

Now do I have to use LAN (Ethernet) cable or I can open that portal if I connected wireless also.

I tried to open tplinklogin.net but I show a page with ads, see image (. When I try by IP address, it takes forever to open. What is the missing? Please help me to change the password by opening the router portal.

[image: tplink panel with ads]

**UPDATE 1:**

One of answer suggest me to open the default gateway IP. My Default gateway IP is 192.168.1.20. If I open it in browser, I get what is given in below image. It's probably my POE [Power over Ethernet
]'s setting panel.

[image]

My router connection is like given below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First you must be knowing about the default gateway(you can find it from the network and sharing center on your computer) about your router it might be 192.168.1.1 or 192.168.0.1 try using in different browsers to open this link and so you can get access to the admin tool of your router and change the password for your router. 
Ensure that you are connected in a Ethernet cable with the router because any changes on the router settings requires a reboot and reconnect to the computer devices.

The username and the password are the same admin and admin.

For more reference about the router access you can refer the below link :

http://setuprouter.com/router/tp-link/tl-wr740n/login.htm

Comment: My default gateway is `192.168.1.20`. When I open it in browser, it opens this, http://i.imgur.com/iNsBJQO.png Do I have to compulsory use Ethernet cable to connect laptop to router? Can't I access router setting while I am connected to Internet wireless via that router?

Comment: Please check my update in question. Thanks :)